# Implementation of an abstract class

Tags: java

I have this abstract class that I want to inherit from:

```
public abstract class MyFirstClass<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Iterable<MySecondClass<K, V>>
{
     // Abstract methods
}
```

I'm not really sure how to write the declaration of the class that extends this abstract class. I thought about something like:

```
public class MyFirstClassImpl<K, V> extends MyFirstClass<Object, Object>
{
    @Override
    public Iterator iterator()
    {
        // Code
    }

    // Implementation of abstract methods from MyFirstClass
}
```

But it dosen't seem to work that way and I have trouble finding an explanation to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sub-class should also be generic, it should have the same generic parameter declaration as the base class :

```
public class MyFirstClassImpl<K extends Comparable<K>, V> extends MyFirstClass<K,V>
{
    @Override
    public Iterator<MySecondClass<K, V>> iterator()
    {
    // Code
    }
}
```

Otherwise, your sub-class shouldn't have any generic type parameters at all :

```
public class MyFirstClassImpl extends MyFirstClass<SomeClassThatImplementsComparable, Object>
{
    @Override
    public Iterator<MySecondClass<SomeClassThatImplementsComparable,Object>> iterator()
    {
        // Code
    }

    // Implementation of abstract methods from MyFirstClass
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for! I need the sub-class to be generic too :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your first parametrized type: `Object`.

`Object` doesn't implement `Comparable<Object>`, thus `K extends Comparable<K>` is not validated by your `Object` parametrization for `K`.

Also note that your `iterator` override should be parametrized too!

An example of a simple implementation of your `abstract` class would be:

```
public class MyFirstClassImpl<K, V> extends MyFirstClass<String, Object> {
    @Override
    public Iterator<MySecondClass<String, Object>> iterator() {
        // TODO
        return null;
    }
}
```

... as `String` implements `Comparable<String>`.